# Drupal 8 - Disable view of structure

Tags: drupal

I'm using drupal 8, and i want to disable the view mode of node, and let user on the edit page after saving a node, but i founded nothing to do that.
Is someone have a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add hook_form_alter() and alter submit action if you detect that node saving form is displayed. Something like:

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

```
//hook_form_alter
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
    if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
      $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'callback_submit';
    }
  }
}


function callback_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('custom.page');
}
```

For details check this page:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163626/how-to-perform-a-redirect-to-custom-page-after-node-save-or-delete

Comment: Is there a way with Rules ? I don't know what put in the url redirection data selector to get url /node/{nid}/edit

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239628/how-to-redirect-to-edit-page-on-node-create